# Mysql When then and temp variable. Explanation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql query that I am trying to understand.
Can I get a line by line explanation please.
I know the first line Initialise variable.
Second line gets the minimum value.

```sql
set @r1=0, @r2=0, @r3=0, @r4=0;
select min(Doctor), min(Professor), min(Singer), min(Actor)
from(
  select case when Occupation='Doctor' then (@r1:=@r1+1)
            when Occupation='Professor' then (@r2:=@r2+1)
            when Occupation='Singer' then (@r3:=@r3+1)
            when Occupation='Actor' then (@r4:=@r4+1) end as RowNumber,
    case when Occupation='Doctor' then Name end as Doctor,
    case when Occupation='Professor' then Name end as Professor,
    case when Occupation='Singer' then Name end as Singer,
    case when Occupation='Actor' then Name end as Actor
  from OCCUPATIONS
  order by Name
) Temp
group by RowNumber
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables are enumerating the rows for each occupation separately.  You can see this by running the subquery to see the results.

It is doing the equivalent of:

```
select max(case when occupation = 'Doctor' then name end) as doctor,
       max(case when occupation = 'Professor' then name end) as professor,
       max(case when occupation = 'Singer' then name end) as singer,
       max(case when occupation = 'Actor' then name end) as actor       
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by occupation order by name) as seqnum
      from occupations o
     ) o
group by seqnum;
```

This is a better way to write the query in MySQL 8+, because such use of variables has been deprecated.  What it is doing is putting the occupations in separate columns:

```
occupation     name
doctor         A
doctor         B
singer         C
```

Turns into:

```
doctor    professor    singer     actor
  A                      C
  B
```

The intermediate step is:

```
occupation     name     seqnum
doctor         A           1
doctor         B           2
singer         C           1
```

Comment: what is the Temp doing before the last line.
Also could you explain what (then name end)
I will appreciate if you can explain your query more, or guide me to some docs.

Comment: @FrankDax . . . That is a table alias.

Comment: Also could you explain what (then name end) I will appreciate if you can explain your query more, or guide me to some docs

Comment: @FrankDax . . .`case` expressions are a basic part of the SQL language and covered by any documentation:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html.